# Is there any way to work around `PATH_MAX` in macOS for long paths in a git repo?

Tags: git, macos, path, filenames, filepath

In macOS, paths cannot be longer than 1024 bytes:

```
command cc -dM -E -xc - <<< '#include <sys/syslimits.h>' | grep -i ' [NP]A.._MAX'
```

```
#define NAME_MAX 255
#define PATH_MAX 1024
```

What can I do to clone a git repo that has paths longer than this limit?

Comment: This is, *I think*, a filesystem limit, not an OS hard limit so try to create a filesystem (on a removable drive, e.g.) with longer paths. You can also try to clone in a real OS running in a virtual machine or a container.

Comment: @phd Is the limit any better on APFS?

Comment: "*It looks like a filename of 255 characters and no path limits.*" Found in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits found in https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/44763/how-long-can-a-file-name-and-path-be-with-the-apfs-file-system#comment54939_44763 found in https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&pws=0&q=APFS+max+path+length

Answer (score 1):

You can clone such a repository, but you won't be able to check it out on macOS.  PATH_MAX, if defined, specifies the maximum length of a path that the operating system supports.  It may be the case that APFS does not itself have a maximum path length, but macOS does.  If, somehow, you could mount this file system on Linux, you'd be able to take advantage of its longer PATH_MAX.

You can use a Linux VM to work with this repository, or you can operate on a bare repository using Git plumbing commands or libgit2 to avoid needing to check it on your system, if that's an option on your use case.